# WooCommerce: Show price in custom loop based on Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, price

I want to make a custom product loop based on a list of products from a relationship field in Advanced Custom Fields.

So far, everything works fine except the display of the product price.

Here's my current code:

```
<?php $featured_posts = $products_select; if( $products_select ): ?>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach( $featured_posts as $post ): setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
                <?php // wc_get_template( 'loop/price.php' ); ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The code shows the products with image, title and ratings. But the price is missing.
The price shows if I uncomment the following line:

```
<?php wc_get_template( 'loop/price.php' ); ?>
```

But that should be a part of `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );`?!

I really want to use `wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' )`. And therefore it would be great if the price would work without extra code.

Is there anything I'm missing in the custom loop?

Comment: It seems like it might be unhooked somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! I figured it out based on your hint. If you want you can add it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem as though the action `woocommerce_template_single_price` has been unhooked somewhere else in your code.

Otherwise, you should be able to re-add it at a later priority

`add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 15);`